# How to vertical centering inside list tiles

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-listview

I've some problems with a ReorderableListView because I can't be able to vertical centering the title, leading and trailing.
As you can see in the Image1

[image]

the leading is nested in a column but it seams that there is a space on top of the column. Even if I remove the column there no change, I've also tried with center and align with no lucky.
I can't figure out what is causing this space.
This is the code of the ReorderableListView:

```
ReorderableListView(
  padding = const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12.0, 0.0, 12.0, 16.0),
  children = <Widget>[
    for (final items in homeButtons)
    Card(
      elevation: 10,
      key: ValueKey(items),
      child: Container(
        height: 50.0,
        width: double.infinity,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          gradient: const RadialGradient(
            colors: [
              Color(0xff3b474f),
              Color(0xff232b32),
            ],
            center: Alignment.topRight,
            radius: 4,
          ),
        ),
        child: ListTile(
          title: Text(
            items.toString().replaceAll('_', ' '),
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: GoogleFonts.outfit(
              textStyle: const TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 18,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w100,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          leading: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: 24.0,
                width: 24.0,
                child: SvgPicture.asset(
                  'assets/homebutton/$items.svg',
                  height: 24.0,
                  width: 24.0,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          trailing: const Icon(
            Icons.navigate_next,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

This image is how it looks now

[image]

and this  is how it has to be like.

[image]

Has you can see they aren't centered by a little space.

Comment: You want to remove extra space in between ListTile -leading, title, trailing?

Comment: Yes, they aren't centered on the vertical axis

Comment: can you add your expected design?

Comment: I've added the image without the debug paint and the expected one

Comment: You can try Transfrom.translate if contentPadding failed to archive the ui

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to define listview inside container , place your listview as a child of Card & assign color property to Card for set background color.

```
 Card(
                   key: ValueKey(items),
                   color: ConstantColor.keyBlack,
                   elevation: 10,
                   child:  ListTile(
                     title: Text(
                       "index : ${i}",
                       textAlign: TextAlign.center,

                       style: GoogleFonts.outfit(
                         textStyle: const TextStyle(
                           color: Colors.white,
                           fontSize: 18,
                           fontWeight: FontWeight.w100,
                         ),
                       ),
                     ),
                     leading: Column(
                       mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                       children: [
                         SizedBox(
                           height: 24.0,
                           width: 24.0,

                           child: SvgPicture.asset(
                             'assets/homebutton/$items.svg',
                             height: 24.0,
                             width: 24.0,
                           ),
                         ),
                       ],
                     ),
                     trailing: const Icon(
                       Icons.navigate_next,
                       color: Colors.white,
                     ),
                   ),
                 ),
```

and comment padding
//padding = const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12.0, 0.0, 12.0, 16.0),